# Scala function not passed by name with curly brackets (braces)

Tags: scala, pass-by-name

I would like to pass a function by name do something before its execution. Consider the following example:

```
class Runner {
  def apply(procedure: => Unit) = {
    println("running procedure")
    procedure
  }
}

new Runner()(println("procedure!")) // #1
new Runner(){println("procedure!")} // #2
```

The only difference between call #1 and #2 is in curly braces. While the first call outputs

```
running procedure
procedure!
```

as expected, in the second call only

```
procedure!
```

is printed.

It seems that when curly braces are used, the procedure is not passed by name but executed instead. **Why are the curly and round brackets not interchangeable in this example?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First statement:**

```
new Runner()(println("procedure!")) // #1
```

In first case, when parenthesis are used, `apply()` method gets invoked and `println("procedure!")` is passed as argument. So the first statement is equivalent to:

```
new Runner().apply(println("procedure!"))
```

Hence the output is:

```
running procedure
procedure!
```

**Second statement:**

```
new Runner(){println("procedure!")} // #2
```

While in second case you are creating an anonymous class by extending `Runner`. So in second case statement `println("procedure!")` is executed as part of constructor but `apply()` is not invoked hence you see only

```
procedure!
```

as output.

**Custom Control Structure**

I suppose you intended to create [custom control structure](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/control-abstraction.html#9.4) by using second statement (though for compiler, it's an anonymous class). If that is the case, you can use below syntax:

```
val runner = new Runner()
runner.apply {println("procedure!")}
// OR simply 
runner {println("procedure!")} // this is possible because apply() is defined for Runner
```

Comment: Right, I didn't see the new anonymous class syntax. Now it makes sense. It's a bit confusing, though, that round and curly brackets are not interchangeable.